# Rpush not adding particular key

Tags: redis

I am facing a quite strange issue in our deployment

After certain time in operation
I could not add a particular list with a particular keyname or listname to Redis using RPUSH.

**Example**

`RPUSH client-send-process-servername TEST`

I am unable to add that key to Redis database.

Anyways the output after executing that command i get 
(Integer) 1
But i could not see the list

```
redis-cli keys *client-send*
```

> Return empty list

However when this problem appears 
I am able successfully execute the following command.

`RPUSH client-send-process-ser TEST`

And 
`redis-cli keys *client-send*`
NOTE: one ASTRICK before n aftet client-send string
Which is not displayed here

It is listing the Queue

`"client-send-process-ser"`

However strangely i could not add a List with specific key say
`client-send-process-servername`

Any ideas to debug further.. where to look and what to look.

Redis Server Version is 2.8

I tired enabling debug logs in redis and tried to use redis-monitor command.

However nothing relevant could be found explaining this issue. I am eager to find a solution. Please if some one could help me to pursue further would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this problem is not reproducible. However I've tested it in my local pc and found that it is working fine.
Example:

```
➜  ~ redis-cli     
127.0.0.1:6379> RPUSH client-send-process-servername TEST
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *client-send*
1) "client-send-process-servername"
127.0.0.1:6379> keys client-send*
1) "client-send-process-servername"
127.0.0.1:6379> RPUSH client-send-process-ser TEST
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> keys client-send*
1) "client-send-process-ser"
2) "client-send-process-servername"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

If there is any option, you can try updating your redis server. current updated versions is **5.0.7** and yours is **2.8**.

Comment: Thanks for reply,Sorry I was not clear "client-send-process-servername" is just a example, the actuall key name is different, However, I have found out the cause. The Problem was there was Several Stale clients executing command, "BLPOP client-send-process-servername 3600" and one of the Clients consumes the Keys.  them before I manually execute the command LRANGE/keys command, basically I was thinking I have stopped all process that consume that Redis Queue, however after analyzing even though I stop those process that consume those queue, I still had Stale Client executing the BLPOP command.

Comment: That means, killing those Clients and when I execute the test, I am able to retrieve the keys..... however the Client keeps piling up which need to be investiagted,  that means, over a time instead of One Client Listening to BLPOP client-send-process-servername 3600, there are several clients piles up executing the same command, need to check why and investigate it further.

Comment: Further, I tried to update to 5.0.7, and have same issue